# Excel Cross Sheet INDEX/MATCH inconsistencies

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

Hi I'm currently trying to run an index match to get values from another table.

My code is this

```
=INDEX(Book2.xlsx!TI[[#All],[03- IL]],MATCH(B4,Book2.xlsx!TI[[#All],[Prog '#]]))
```

I have my values to match against in column B, they are all numbers in the 100-900 range. I am matching them against another table on another sheet with numbers in the same range.

I value I want to pull into this sheet is in the other one in line with the matches in the table.

The problem I have is only some values are pulling correctly. Most wont pull, all of them only appear once. I've included pictures of my tables with the relevant information blurred out. I've tried formatting all the cells as numbers, text, and general.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbTRZ.jpg

Comment: You are doing a nearest match (by leaving out the 3rd parameter of Match, defaults to 1) which requires search column to be sorted, which it is not.  Add a `0` as the 3rd parameter

Comment: IT WORKED, Thank you so much! Can't believe I missed a syntax field.

Answer (score 0):

Chris Neilsen Answered my question above.

"You are doing a nearest match (by leaving out the 3rd parameter of Match, defaults to 1) which requires search column to be sorted, which it is not. Add a 0 as the 3rd parameter" – chris neilsen